# 英語が残っている： ヘルプ センター > 信用度とモデレーション

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語, ヘルプ

「[ヘルプ センター > 信用度とモデレーション](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)」のページに英語が残っています。

> What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?

サイドバーにも残っています。

[image: eigo ga nokotteiru]

Comment: ヘルプセンターでは英語が相当残っています。文字の量も多いし、将来にヘルプを日本語版でどうしようとかを悩み中です。このページは重要なんで、タイトルだけですし、すぐ直しますが、和訳案をいただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 「信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？」に訂正しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jmacさんのコメントより](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457/%e8%8b%b1%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e6%ae%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-%e3%83%98%e3%83%ab%e3%83%97-%e3%82%bb%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc-%e4%bf%a1%e7%94%a8%e5%ba%a6%e3%81%a8%e3%83%a2%e3%83%87%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3#comment439_1457)

> 「信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？」に訂正しました。

Answer (score 2):

対訳案：

> 信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら獲得でき（または失い）ますか？